# Do active filters exist that don't cause a voltage drop?

Tags: power-supply, filter, noise, active-filter

Pretty much all filters I have come across always cause some sort of voltage drop. A passive example is the classic RC filter, an active example is the capacitance multiplier (which is basically just an active RC filter).

I understand that some power must be used to power the filter, but is there a way that the voltage can be held constant, and the input current can be increased instead?

I should note that I am interested in applying this filter on a power supply, so low output impedance is important.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  An active filter can designed to have gain > 1.  Perhaps if you were more detailed.

Comment: Voltage drop where? Input? Output? With respect to what? Being connected (vs no-load voltage)? Versus frequency? (A filter is defined as a block which exhibits some change in amplitude and/or phase over frequency.) Active filters are very rarely employed for power supplies, for obvious(??) reasons, though there are some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if this is for a DC or AC power supply.

If it's low-pass filter for the output or input of a DC power supply, use an LC filter. The inductor can be sized so the resistance at DC will cause minimal DC losses. You may need to de-Q the inductor by adding a resistor (generally 5 to 30 ohms) across the inductor. This reduces ringing of the filter.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not clear what you mean by "voltage drop", my guess is that you are talking about the minimum input-output differential voltage.  For a linear regulator circuit for a power supply, this has to be greater than 0 V.  If there is no voltage difference between the input and the output, the circuit isn't doing any regulating.

There are circuit techniques that can reduce this differential to a very low value, as in 0.1 V at an output current of several amps.  Note that if the incoming DC has a ripple voltage component that is greater than the in-out diff voltage, ripple will appear at the output.

Answer (score 0):

When speaking about "voltage drop",I suppose you mean change of "magnitude" ?
According to Bode`s relation each phase change (and this is the real core of signal filering) is connected with a correspondung change in magnitude.